# how to set input endpoints in azure cloud service programmatically?

Tags: java, azure, sdk

I am creating a cloud service on azure with 2 virtual machines using java sdk.  Service created successfully and its running also but when I check the input endpoints of newly created cloud service its saying "No endpoints found". But I am setting end points details at virtual machine creation. Here's the code snippet.

```
ArrayList<InputEndpoint> endPointList = new ArrayList<InputEndpoint>();

InputEndpoint endPoint = new InputEndpoint();

endPoint.setName("ssh");

endPoint.setPort(22);

endPoint.setLocalPort(22);

endPoint.setProtocol("tcp");

endPointList.add(endPoint);


configurationSetList = new ArrayList<ConfigurationSet>();

configurationSet = new ConfigurationSet();


configurationSet.setConfigurationSetType(ConfigurationSetTypes.LINUXPROVISIONINGCONFIGURATION);

configurationSet.setComputerName(roleName);

configurationSet.setUserName(userName);

configurationSet.setUserPassword(pswd);
                        configurationSet.setAdminPassword(adminUserPassword);

configurationSet.setAdminUserName(adminUserName);

configurationSet.setEnableAutomaticUpdates(false);

configurationSet.setHostName(clusterName + ".cloudapp.net");

configurationSet.setInputEndpoints(endPointList);

configurationSetList.add(configurationSet);


ArrayList<Role> roleList = new ArrayList<Role>();

Role role = new Role();

role.setRoleName(roleName);

role.setRoleType(VirtualMachineRoleType.PersistentVMRole.toString());

role.setRoleSize(VirtualMachineRoleSize.SMALL);

role.setProvisionGuestAgent(true);

role.setConfigurationSets(configurationSetList);

role.setOSVirtualHardDisk(oSVirtualHardDisk);

roleList.add(role);
```

Please tell me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I am able set the input end points using update call. Once I create the vms, I call update method for setting up the input endpoints.

Comment: But now having another problem. Even though input endpoints set properly, I am not able to do ssh  on some of VMs. Its in-consistence actually. Some time works some time doesn't. 

I can see endpoints details on azure portal and once I do a restart on that particular VM using azure portal, everything works fine.

I am creating cloud service and virtual machines using java sdk and setting up input endpoints also. I am setting the endpoint after checking the state of VM. Once its become "ReadyRole", I set the endpoint and then restart the VM. Though, I am not sure restart is needed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need create other ConfigurationSet,

```
ConfigurationSet configurationSetForNetwork = new ConfigurationSet(); 

configurationSetForNetwork.setConfigurationSetType(ConfigurationSetTypes.NETWORKCONFIGURATION);
configurationSetList.add(configurationSetForNetwork);
configurationSetList.add(otherConfigurationSet...);
...
configurationSetForNetwork.setInputEndpoints(endPointList);
//If you need the one public ip
PublicIP publicIP = new PublicIP();
publicIP.setName(vitualNetworkName);//VNET Name
ArrayList publicIPS = new ArrayList();
publicIPS.add(publicIP);
configurationSetForNetwork.setPublicIPs(publicIPS);
```